# C++ Expected typer specifier error when defining and object within a class definiton

Tags: c++

```
class Player{
    private:
        
        //0 = blank
        //1 = hit
        //miss = 2
        Ship smallShip1(2);
        Ship smallShip2(2);
        Ship bigShip(3);
        int screenStateArray[5][5] ={{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0}};

        
        
    public:
        
        void displayScreen();
        void placeShip();

};
```

I encounter the error when trying to make objects of the ship class, first 3 lines after the comment.I'm able to create ship objects in regular functions.
The definition of the ship class

```
class Ship{
    private:
        int length;
        int x;
        int y;
        char alive = 1;
        int rotation = 12;//clock
        int numHits =0;
    public:
        Ship(int);
        Ship();
        void UpdateLocation(int,int);
        int getX();
        int getY();
        int getRotation();
        void hit();
        char isAlive();
        

};
```

The constructor used for ship:

```
Ship::Ship(int size){
    length = size;
}
```

Compile Error:
[image]

Error in vs code:

[image]

Comment: Do not post errors as images.

Comment: Side note whenever you have to describe something with a comment you are probably missing some code. E.g.  a function, or a type like `enum class ShipInfo { Blank, Hit, Miss };`

Comment: I'm going to stand down on the [mre] solves everything on this one. You're missing a bit of information. You can't use the `()`-style initialization in an in-definition initialization. You need to use the `{}` style. And you can't do in definition initialization at all unless you're compiling to C++11 or newer.

Comment: Have you done the header include for `Ship` before referencing it in `Player`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you distingish this code is wether class type member or method?

```
class Library {
private:
    Book book1(2);
    Book book2();
};
```

In ambiguous statements, compiler also same. So, compiler can't compile it. 
If you want to use in-class member initializers, consider **implicit type conversion** of classes.

```
class Player {
private:
    Ship smallShip1 = 2;  // int to Ship
    Ship smallShip2 = 2;
    Ship bigShip = 3;
    int screenStateArray[5][5] = ...;


public:
    void displayScreen();
    void placeShip();
};
```

you can read more informations [cppreferences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

Comment: You can also `Ship smallShip1{1};`